# How can i make an image that takes me to another page when i click on it?

Tags: html

I have written this HTML code, but i am wondering: How can I make an image that will take me to another page when i click on it?

```
<html>
<title><h2>My personal web</title></h2>
<head></head>
<body> 
    <a href="www.google.com"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!--If you have to redirect to internet page -->
<html>
<head></head>
<body> 
    <a href="www.google.com"><img src="picture.jpg" /></a>
</body>
</html>


<!--If you have to redirect to your own page -->
<html>
<head></head>
<body> 
    <a href="page1.html"><img src="picture.jpg" /></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much , it was just what I was looking for